# Import specific branch to AOSP gitlab server

Tags: gitlab, push, android-source, pull

I want to import a specific AOSP branch to local Gitlab server, and then be able to edit certain files with the GUI.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base

branch: android-9.0.0_r33

I am able to download/git clone the repository, as far as I can tell at least. I'm not able to find it in my Gitlab GUI, however.

The command I used is

```
git clone -b android-9.0.0_r33 --single-branch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
```

How can I push this newly cloned repo to my server?

I tried cloning it in this dir on my server:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/myGroupName/
```

It seems like there is a slightly different file structure between gits imported with the GUI and the one running the git clone command.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like there is a slightly different file structure between gits imported with the GUI and the one running the git clone command.

I'm not sure I understand the bit above, but once you've done the clone, you can push the local repo to your GitLab instance directly. You can also do it in a way that it creates a new project for you in GitLab, if it doesn't already exist:

```
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
```

[GitLab documentation - Push to create a new project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this:
git push --set-upstream myUserName@MyIPAddress:MyGroup/frameworks_basee.git android-9.0.0_r31
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I have no git called frameworks_basee.git, how I understood your line of code, that would be made instantly?

Comment: Okay, so I figured something out
git push --set-upstream git@myIP:MyProjectName/someRandomName android-9.0.0_r33

What happened is that it created the repo. It took quite the while.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured something out, thank you yet again.
git push --set-upstream git@myIP:MyProjectName/someRandomName android-9.0.0_r33

What happened is that it created the repo. It took quite the while.

Enumerating objects: 2807425, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2807425/2807425), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (504633/504633), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2807425/2807425), 2.09 GiB | 10.71 MiB/s, done.
Total 2807425 (delta 1913688), reused 2807425 (delta 1913688)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1913688/1913688), done.
remote: Checking connectivity: 2807425, done.

The repository for this project is empty
Could it be because I am cloning a tag, and not a branch?